# Problems with jquery cycle pager function - page not showing up

Tags: jquery, cycle

Using cycle 2.7x i didn't have any problem with this however I had to upgrade to jquery cycle 2.88 because 2.7x doesn't support cleartypeNoBg. Below is the code I am using. As I say it worked before.

```
$('#hero').cycle({
            fx:     'scrollHorz',
            speed:   2000,
            timeout: 12000,
            next:   '#next',
            prev:   '#prev',
            pager:   '#pager',
            pagerAnchorBuilder: pagerFactory

        });

        function pagerFactory(idx, slide) {
            var s = idx > 2 ? ' style="display:none"' : '';
            return '<li'+s+'><a href="#" '+s+'><img src="images/nav/invisi.png" height="16px" width="16px" /></a></li>';

        };

<ul id="pager"></ul>
```

Any help anyone can provide will be much appreciated.

--EDIT--

I have solve the problem. It was all in the styles